# How do I view records from a table in a different schema?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

Besides using linked server, how do I view records from a table in a different schema?

so if I have table in [eg].[info] and another table in [ie].[info], how do I join them together?  That is one schema is [eg] and the other is schema [ie].

Comment: Don't use standard grammatical abbreviations as names. Alternatively, use them correctly if your goal according to the language standards. You just add confusion using them in this fashion. Linked servers and schema names have no direct relationship - is that an issue here? If you need to refer to a table, best practice is to ALWAYS use a 2 part name - [schema].[table]. And best practice is to ALWAYS give every table a short (but not cryptic) alias and then use that alias when referencing every column.

Answer (score 0):

You need to alias the tables with `AS` (which you should always do anyway):

```sql
FROM eg.info AS info1
JOIN ie.info AS info2
```

Comment: Alias is a good idea, but doesn't SQL Server support ANSI SQL `schema.table.column` syntax, e.g. `eg.info.id = ie.info.id`?

Comment: @jarlh See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ms143729(v=sql.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), it's been deprecated, although I think it still works : "Three-part and four-part column references."

Comment: The thing is one cannot read a table from one schema in another schema unless one uses linked server.  yes it is odd.  so, I was wondering if there was an alternative.

Comment: What, that is simply untrue, just use two-part table name with aliases

Comment: you are right.  it is deprecated now.  I thought I was imagining things.  I used three part name and got the following error. ...is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL server 2018 upwards, it is deprecated.  Error I get with three part name is ...is not supported in this version of SQL Server.